# Why is the model binding not working? ASP.NET Core 5.0 RazorPages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

ASP.NET Core 5.0 Razor Pages.

When posting the array, the model is not binding - value is showing empty array.

This is a JSON array posted using Ajax  -

```
[
    { "Order":1, "FileName":"bbed5ecf-4133-4681-b0f3-c11366ad3186.jpg" },
    { "Order":2, "FileName":"737e60dc-0631-493d-947d-2f5948d7818c.jpg" },
    { "Order":3, "FileName":"6c76f9d1-44bd-4b80-926e-2ce4307eb30b.jpg"}
]

function UpdateImageOrder() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/property/imagesorter",
    dataType: "json",
    headers:
    {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(newOrderDictionary),
    success: function (response) {

    }
});

}
```

RazorPage action Method

```
 public async Task OnPostAsync(ImageOrder[] data)
 {
 }

 public class ImageOrder
 {
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` parameter of the POST should be the object value, not a stringified version of it. Try changing to:

```
...
data: newOrderDictionary,
...
```

Assuming `newOrderDictionary` is an array.

Comment: Yes it is an array = removed stringify - same result - model binding is not working. Example of array data at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Considering using post to pass data, you need to add `contentType:"application/json"` in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/?handler",
            dataType: "json",

            contentType:"application/json",
            //...
        });
```

In addition, add `[FromBody]` in the bakend.

```
    public async Task OnPostAsync([FromBody]ImageOrder[] data)
    {

    }
```

Then, it can get the data.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that this works :

```
 public async Task OnPostAsync(ImageOrder[] order)
 {
 }


function UpdateImageOrder() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/property/imagesorter",
    dataType: "json",
    headers:
    {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: {
        order: newOrderDictionary
    },

    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: You just used @NoahStahl answer and shoulg give the credits to him.